# Add icon to matplotlib plot pie

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to add image from external file to `matplotlib plot pie` to the place of `autopct`

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the intent of your question is to replace the numeric display of the pie chart with an icon, and I have placed the Windows 10 logo in place of the icon. Get the coordinates of the displayed value in the pie chart. Place it in the annotation box specifying its image. I used an example from the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-demo-annotation-box-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = plt.imread('./data/Windows_logo.svg')

imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.2)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

patches, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)# autopct='%1.1f%%',
xy = (autotexts[1].get_position()[0], autotexts[1].get_position()[1])
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,
                    xybox=(5., 15.),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.5,
                    bboxprops={'edgecolor':'white'}
                    )
ax.add_artist(ab)
ax.axis('equal')
for t in autotexts:
    t.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example code below, where the image position is the x and y coordinates:

```
import matplotlib, scipy
fig = matplotlib.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5])
axicon = fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4])
ax.plot(range(5), [1,2,3,4,5])
axicon.imshow(scipy.randn(100,100))
axicon.set_xticks([])
axicon.set_yticks([])
fig.show()
```